# Task queues in python

Tags: python, class, queue, instance, scheduler

I have a class instance which is supposed to run in the background. Hence the instance would be running continuously. I have a scheduler inside the instance.

```
class background(object):
schedule.every().day.at("11:00").do(check_status())
```

The scheduler triggers a method to read a value from a queue and execute a method.

```
    def check_status(self, val):
    execute(val)
```

The queue needs to be populated via two flask APIs .

```
@App.route('/foo', methods = ['GET'])
def func():
    bck = background()
```

How does one implement the queue in such a way that the queue for the same instance is updated through the APIs and a method inside the instance executes based on the queue list?

Comment: `'\foo\'` is not valid. It is an unterminated string. Did you mean to use forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: Something like threads and mutexes/semaphores? To be honest, I'm not 100% sure I understood your issue.

Comment: What I meant to ask is, is there a way to manage queues of tasks populated via different APIs without storing them to any database? More like https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager ?